# How suppress Group Header if not Detail is display

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm doing a report where I am counting the row of the detail in a Running Total field. This is the only way to get what I need from my database field called `#count3`. The Detail Section Expert has a formula in Suppress:

`if IsNull({#count3}) or {#count3} = 1 then True else False`

This works fine in suppressing the detail of the customers I don't need.

The problem is that I also need to suppress the Group header for customers with no detail. (already suppressed)

When I put the same formula in the Group Header Section Expert, all the customer header get suppressed.

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Running Total that counts one the fields in the detail row.
- Evaluate based on Change on the Group Header field
- Reset based on Change of group Header field

[image]

The Running Total value should be zero any time there is no records in details.

Use the Suppress Formula and apply to both Details and Group Header

If your Running Total is called RTotal0, then your formula is `{#Rtotal0} = 0`

[image]

Once I applied the Suppress Formulas, it worked for me. I wanted to Suppress any Inventory ItemNum that do not have BINs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have "master-child" relationship in your data source then you can just link 2 tables which you are showing on report with `inner join`. You drag from master to child table key by key. Double click on connection of link and you can change from inner to outer join etc (picture)... In your case you need inner join.

[image]

This avoids any underlying logic and keep your report simple and easy to maintain.